# Can't update the v-for list when ajax update the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I using a datepicker and using javascript to pass the date to the vue instance, but after the first time render the list using v-for, when i call the function with other date, it keeps the previous one data on display.
Here is the function i have:

```
function updateDate(fdate) {
var datefieldVal = document.getElementById('date').value;
var locationfieldVal = document.getElementById('location').value;
if (datefieldVal && locationfieldVal) {
   var tslot = new Vue({
        el: '#time-slots-container',
        data: {
            slot: {}
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.fetchTimeslot();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchTimeslot: function () {
                var that = this;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: timeslotApiURL + "?date='" +fdate+ "'",
                    contentType: "application/json;",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        that.slot = JSON.parse(data.d);


                        setTimeout(showTimeSlotAndButton, 500);
                    }
                });

            }
});
}
}
```

anyone have idea, how to update the v-for list using the new slot data? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your data is coming back correctly, it's probably just that the `slot` is not reactive. Try:

```
success: function (data) {
  Vue.set(that.$data, 'slot', JSON.parse(data.d))
  ...
```

Looking at the above code you should avoid creating and mounting a new instance every time you want to update the date. I'm unsure what Vue would do in this scenario but it may just fail as you can't mount another instance to an existing one.

Instead move all your Vue code outside of the updateDate function.

Then if you need to prevent the v-for from firing until you have the data, just add a data param of `dateReady` and set this to true when you have completed the ajax request, i.e.

```
data: {
  slot: {},
  dateReady: false,
},
...

success: function (data) {
  Vue.set(that.$data, 'slot', JSON.parse(data.d))
  that.dateReady = true
  ...
```

then you can just add `v-if="dateReady"` to your `v-for` element:

```
<div v-if="dateReady" class="time-slot-row" v-for="hourly in slot.TimeSlot">
```

how you pass `fdate` to the ajax request is now handled differently, but you could have something like:

```js
var datefieldVal = document.getElementById('date').value;
var locationfieldVal = document.getElementById('location').value;

if (!datefieldVal || !locationfieldVal)

 return
    
var tslot = new Vue({
    el: '#time-slots-container',
    data: {
        slot: {},
        dateReady: false,
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.fetchTimeslot();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchTimeslot: function() {
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: timeslotApiURL + "?date='" + that.getDate() + "'",
                contentType: "application/json;",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    that.slot = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    that.dateReady = true
                    setTimeout(showTimeSlotAndButton, 500);
                }
            });

        },
        getDate () {
            // whatever you do here
            return ''
        },
    },
})

// wherever else you are using this...
tslot.fetchTimeslot()
```

Essentially you move more of the logic into Vue's instance, i.e `getDate()` if that isn't possible then you could set up a param to hold the date you want to fetch, use that in the ajax call and create a new method to update it. Lots of ways around it but the main issue is ensuring you only have a single instance of vue bound to that `#time-slots-container` element

Comment: hi, GuyC, thanks for your reply. Yes, i have checked the data received is correct, after using the above syntax,,also seems not working, it keeps the previous one data. i think the slot data have been changed, just the render the list not reactive, any idea?

Comment: sorry just noticed you're trying to rebuild the vue instance every time you run updateDate. Updated answer

Comment: After move Vue code outside the updateDate function, how to call and pass the fdate param to the vue at the updateDate function?

Comment: updated the answer but overall you need to start using Vue more - stuff like the `if (datefieldVal ...` checks are just not what you do. In Vue you can bind the value of that input to a param on your Vue instance, i.e. `<input v-model="date" type="text">`, then it becomes simple to access it via `this.date`. I'd probably do a little more reading in the Vue docs as you'll no doubt find a lot of things you can refactor to improve the way you are coding this.

Comment: now i move out the vue code outside the javascript function, but can't call it using tslot.fetchTimeslot();   any idea?

Comment: I'd assume that if it isn't throwing an error about `tslot` being undefined then you're calling it prior to the App being created. Ideally you want to refactor so that any calls to `fetchTimeslot()` are from within the Vue App, then you'll know the state of that app

Answer (score 0):

here is the v-for code:

```
                <div class="time-slots-list-container">
                <p class="description"><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("OPTBSRES","SelectedStartTime") %> <span v-if="slot.SelectedSlot==null"><%=GetGlobalResourceObject("OPTBSRES","ToBeSelect") %></span><span v-if="slot.SelectedSlot!=null">{{slot.SelectedSlot}}</span> <%=GetGlobalResourceObject("OPTBSRES","ExamTimeReminderMsg") %></p>
                  <div class="time-slot-row" v-for="hourly in slot.TimeSlot">
                      <div class="hourly-indicator"><span class="time">{{hourly.Hour}}</span></div>
                      <ul class="time-slots-list">
                            <li v-for="timeslot in hourly.Slots" class="time-slot" v-bind:class="{'selected': timeslot.Status=='selected', 'unavailable': timeslot.Status =='unavailable', 'active': timeslot.Status=='available'}" v-on:click="updateSelectedSlot(hourly,timeslot), timeslot.Status='selected'">
                              <span class="time">{{timeslot.Time}}</span>
                              <div class="selected-indicator"><span aria-hidden="true" class=" fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
                            </li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `data` as a method, not just an object in order for it to be reactive.

```
var tslot = new Vue({
  el: '#time-slots-container',
  data() {
    return {
      slot: {}
    }
  },
  // etc
```

You can also use `this.$http.get({})` as a promise which will remove your whole jquery mess.

Then you can use a fat arrow `=>` to get a lexical this into your promise so you don't have to pass around context (`that`)

If you do all that then your data should be reactive.

Comment: Hi, darryn.ten, thanks for your reply. Sorry, i am a beginner of using vue.js, can you explain more how to use => in order to reactive the data, thanks~

Comment: you don't actually need to do this here as you are using the data attribute of your root instance, if it were a component the above would be correct.

Comment: you can read about that [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#arrows-and-lexical-this)